# showing independence of Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

I was doing some past exams on distributions, and I can not do part e), nor do I understand the mark scheme. The first 4 questions I did as workings below, but can anyone help me try to understand and show part e)?
[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking the question is un-answerable since they say it is a "Poisson distribution" (which is for a single random variable that does not specify timing) rather than a "Poisson process" (which is for a process with i.i.d. inter-arrival times).  Nevertheless they want you to use the fact of Poisson processes that, conditioned on $k$ arrivals occuring in a given interval $[0,T]$, the arrivals are independent and are uniformly distributed over that interval.

Comment: Michael, I'm not sure I see your point. The total number of arrivals in a Poisson process during a fixed time interval is a Poisson random variable, no? And the sum of two Poisson variables is another Poisson variable. That's all that's required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suppose Archie's emails per day $(X_1,X_2)$ are distributed as a Poisson($\lambda$), so his email count over two days $(Y = X_1+X_2)$ is distributed as Poisson($2\lambda$). The probability that Archie received exactly 10 emails on each of the first two days, given that he received a total of 20 emails over the two days, is
$$P = \frac{P(X_1=10) P(X_2=10)}{P(Y=20)} = \frac{\left(\frac{\lambda^{10} e^{-\lambda}}{10!}\right)^2}{\frac{(2\lambda)^{20} e^{-2\lambda}}{20!}} = \frac{20!}{(10!)^2 2^{20}}$$
which does not depend on $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for this.